# Table shift to left when one column hide in jasper table?

Tags: jasper-reports, right-to-left

I am using jasper report and trying to make RTL report.  My problem is that when I am hiding my column in table using `printWhenExpression` based on some condition my table shift to left. I am using below code to hide column in table.

```
<jr:column width="160" uuid="f9b26e92-337e-4fb9-a091-4a81469c6c49">
   <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[System.getProperty("vehicle.event.uid.enabled").equals("true")]]></printWhenExpression>
   <jr:columnHeader style="ColumnHeader" height="30" rowSpan="1">
      <textField>
         <reportElement style="ColumnHeader" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="30" uuid="b4043ada-2580-4602-9262-3791ce3c0807"/>
         <textElement>
            <font size="8" isBold="true" isItalic="false"/>
         </textElement>
         <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$R{target.external.id}]]></textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
   </jr:columnHeader>
   <jr:detailCell style="table_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
      <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
         <reportElement style="TableTextContent" x="0" y="0" width="160" height="20" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true" uuid="9dc36daa-d5e5-417c-831d-ff1b92ef1b79"/>
         <textElement>
            <font size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
         </textElement>
         <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{personExternalId}]]></textFieldExpression>
      </textField>
   </jr:detailCell>
</jr:column>
```

is there is any way so that my table should not shift to left when one of its column which is on left in that table is dynamically hide?

Comment: Do you need just to hide text (using same number of columns) or do you need to make a shift at opposite direction?

Comment: Do you want to have blank column instead of it shifting to left ??

Comment: I want to show/hide column based on some condition but do not want table to shif to left.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the column and does not want text, remove print when condition on column and add it to text expression :

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[System.getProperty("vehicle.event.uid.enabled").equals("true")?$R{target.external.id} : ""]]></textFieldExpression>
```

Comment: I want to hide that column based on some condition. But do not want table to shift left as i am creating RTL report.